# mongodb & google maps - get locations on radius without inaccuracy

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, google-maps, radius

I have locations stored in mongodb that look like this in mongoose schema:

```
location: {
    type: [Number],
    index: '2d'
}
```

And on web client I'm using google maps api with custom radius resizer:

[image]

On each drag I'm making request with radius value that is calculated on client. Radius is the distance between pink arrow marker and center coordinates:

```
function metersToMiles (meters) {
    return meters * 0.000621371192;
}

google.maps.event.addListener(this.sizer, 'dragend', () => {
    const radius = this.circle.getRadius();
    const radiusValue = Math.round(metersToMiles(radius) * 10) / 10; // convert to tenths (this is shown on UI as well)
    this.props.onRadiusChange(radiusValue); // it's a react component
});
```

In mongodb request I'm using `$nearSphere` with radius in `$maxDistance`:

```
function milesToRadian(miles){
   const earthRadiusInMiles = 3963.2;
   return parseFloat(miles) / earthRadiusInMiles;
}
const { radius, lat, lon } = req.query;
const coords = (lat && lon) ? [lat, lon] : ukCoordinates;
const radians = milesToRadian(radius);
console.log('%s, %s, %s', radius, coords, radians);
// what I receive: 1.6, 0.00040371417036737993, [ 51.507351, -0.127758 ]

// ...
{
   $nearSphere: coords,
   $maxDistance: radians
}
```

However if you take a look on the gif image you'll see that there's some inaccuracy in results. For now I'm stucked with it, could you suggest what is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the problem was really funny but still tricky. I've found out that in MongoDB you need to store coordinate pairs as `[longitude, latitude]` and not vice versa:

```
location: {
   type: [Number], // longitude, latitude
   index: '2d'
}
```

But in Google Maps SDK the order is different:

```
new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
```

So to fix my problem I've needed to store coordinates in right order in MongoDB.